# Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not read metadata

Tags: linux, performance, testing, jmeter, report

I'm trying to run jmeter load testing scripts in non GUI mode to generate HTML report with below command

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t "/home/dsbloadtest/DSB_New_21_01_2022/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/dsb_test_plans/SERVICE_BOOKING.jmx" -l /home/dsbloadtest/DSB_New_21_01_2022/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/dsb_test_results/testresults.csv -e -o /home/dsbloadtest/DSB_New_21_01_2022/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/dsb_test_results/HTMLReports
```

It was working fine, but now not getting the result as im getting as below

```
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = \*\*\*\*\*\*/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Apr 01 11:22:40 IST 2022 (1648792360414)
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not read metadata !
... end of run
```

I have tried to generate HTML report in J meter non GUI mode.

Answer (score 0):

> summary = 0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg: 0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err: 0 (0.00%)

it means that JMeter didn't execute any [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), your  `testresults.csv` is empty and you don't have any data to generate the dashboard from.

The reason for test failure normally can be figured out from [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), the most common mistakes are:

- the file referenced in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) doesn't exist
- the [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) used in the test are not installed for this particular JMeter instance